# React native navigation 5 combining stack and tab navigator visibility in every stack

Tags: react-native

I'm just playing around with react native

my first attempt. I'm following the Maximilian Schwarzmüller

course on Udemy but he is using navigation 4 and I want

to use version 5 so I came up with this code:

```
const tabs = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Categories" component={CategoriesScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Favorites" component={FavoritesScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
<NavigationContainer theme={MyTheme}>
  <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Categories">
    <Stack.Screen name="Categories" component={tabs} />
    <Stack.Screen name="CategoryMeal" component={CategoryMealScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="MealDetail" component={MealDetailScreen} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>;
```

But doing so I can see the tab navigation in Categories screen

how can set up the code to see the tab navigation
in CategoryMeal e MealDetail as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to keep the `CategoriesScreen`, `CategoryMealScreen` and `MealDetailScreen` inside the `Tabs` and other screens in the Stack. For this navigation config, you can try the following arrangement of screens:

```js
const tabs = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Categories" component={CategoriesScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="CategoryMeal" component={CategoryMealScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="MealDetail" component={MealDetailScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
<NavigationContainer theme={MyTheme}>
  <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="TabNavigator">
    <Stack.Screen name="TabNavigator" component={tabs} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Favorites" component={FavoritesScreen} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```